# background-image y las rutas relativas

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, quiero usar para la barra de usuario una imagen mediante este código:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-laravel"
style="background-image: url('usuario/sacarino.jpg');">
```

Con esto logro que se vea la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en caso de que sea una dirección más compleja, como aquellas en las que se filtra segun una variable, puede fallar y no mostrarse la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen la tengo en la carpeta public/usuario. ¿Como accedo a ella sin importar donde este?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar una ruta absoluta para referenciar la imagen, tipo:

```
https://miSitioWeb/public/usuario/nombreDeTuImagen.png
```

Pero ya que estás usando un **framework** podrías aprovecharte de que estos suelen tener funciones que te devuelven la **url** base del sitio. En **Laravel** tienes diversas maneras dependiendo de desde donde quieras obtenerla, al tratar de hacerlo desde una **vista** te recomiendo:

**Para versiones inferiores a la 5.2**

```
echo url();
```

**Para versiones 5.2 o superiores**

```
echo url('/');
```

En tu **HTML** tan solo tendrías que añadirle al atributo `style` lo siguiente:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-laravel"
style="background-image: url("<?php echo url('/public/usuario/nombreDeTuImagen.png') ?>");">
```

**Referencia**
[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls)